# Is it possible to sed -i from a text file to another text file?

Tags: unix, debian, shell, regex, sed

I'm coding a shell script on my Debian box and there's a line on the script that needs to delete some emails from a textfile that is full of emails, like this:

```
sed -i '/email01@hotmail.com\|email02@gmail.com\|email03@yahoo.com/d' /myfolder/my_email_list.txt
```

This command works but as this list is getting kinda big, I was thinking if there is a way for me to store all the emails that I want sed to delete on a list (text file), because when I need a new email to be added, I would just edit the list instead of editing the script and including it in the expression.

Is something like this able to be done?

Answer (score 0):

There may well be a way of doing this natively in `sed` but here are some other options:

1. `grep`

   ```
   grep -vFf badmails.txt my_email_list.txt > tempfile && 
     mv tempfile my_email_list.txt
   ```

   Here, you are giving `grep` a list of patterns (`-f`) to search for, telling it to treat them as simple strings (`-F`) and asking for those lines that do *not* (`-v`) match any of them. Finally, you redirect the output to a temporary file and then rename the file to overwrite the original.
2. Perl

   ```
   perl -i -e 'open($f,"badmails.txt"); map{$k{$_}++}<$f>; 
               while(<>){print unless defined($k{$_})}' my_email_list.txt
   ```

   This opens `badmails.txt`, saves each line as the key to a [hash](http://www.zentut.com/perl-tutorial/perl-hash/), then runs through each line of `my_email_list.txt` (`while(<>){}`) and prints it unless the same line (email) was present in `badmails.txt`, that is unless the corresponding value is defined in the hash (`print unless defined($k{$_})`)
3. `sed` and shell:

   ```
   while read badmail; do 
     sed -i sed -i "/$badmail/d" my_email_list.txt ;
   done < badmails.txt
   ```

   or, use the shell to build the list of mails you want to delete, e.g. `me@mine.com\|you@yours.net` and pass that to `sed`:

   ```
   bad=$(while read b; do printf "%s\|" "$b"; done < badmails.txt|
         sed 's/\\|$//')
   sed -i "/$bad/d" my_email_list.txt
   ```